# .NET ModelState.IsValid is calculated before function is called

Tags: .net

I am trying to figure out how .NET (version 6.0) is working with ApiControllers. I have a simple example, but need to understand how this works to provide more advance usage in future. I am using [ApiController] attribute on the controller.

Let's take a UserDTO Object:

```
public class UserDTO
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 6)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

In my controller, my logger line is NEVER called.  The validation is always happening before this function is called.  Also, if I put a break point at the first line of function, it's never hitting the breakpoint.  Does .NET do this validation before entering the function?   What's the point of people calling ModelState.IsValid??  It would never be possible to get there?  What am I missing?

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] UserDTO userDTO)
        {

// debugger never gets to here
            _logger.LogInformation($"Registration Attempt for {userDTO.Email}");
            //if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            //{
            //    return BadRequest(ModelState);
            //}

            try
            {
```

Comment: please post cshtml code as well.

Comment: What does your Register endpoint return right now?

Comment: Api controller makes a validation before entering the  action. So you don't need to call IsValid, it will be always true. If you don't like it remove [APIController] attribute

Comment: Thanks Serge,  This pointed me in the right direction.  I'll detail out in answer

Answer (score 0):

The [ApiController] attribute on the top of the controller is what is making this happen.

```
namespace Net6StarterApp.Authentication.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]   // this is doing magic! 
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
```

See docs:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#apicontroller-attribute

Calling (!ModelState.IsValid) in the method is completely unnecessary as only valid models will even enter the function.

I also saw some people not wanting this action so they could enrich data if not passed in.  I would probably create a new DTO (object) to have different validation attributes.  Then pass into controller method and now you can add/modify data to your liking.